# How does one define chirality of a Dirac cone from low-energy Dirac theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, effective-field-theory

The question is as title in the context of condensed matter physics. By Dirac cone I mean the bands in momentum space touch at some k-point and thus forming Dirac cones. This gives rise to low-energy effective massless theory: Dirac theory. However, different from high-energy massless theory: QED, I don't see an analogous definition of chirality as in Weyl spinors, which is an eigen state of $\gamma_5$. There, we can project out left or right-handed states by using $\frac{1 \pm \gamma_5}{2}$ as projector.

I guess an intuitive way is to define a direction from +1 to -1 (this correspond to the sign of the Berry curvatures in the upper/lower Dirac bands, since Berry curvature sums up to 0) and this direction defines chirality?

Comment: I see some votes for close the question... I just added some clarifications and hope now is more clear what I'm asking?